# Content cutting off to right side when browser windows resizes

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive, window-resize

I have a website I'm making and the content is cutting off to the right. I have `overflow-x: hidden;` on purpose. Is there a possible way to keep all content within the browser window when resized. I don't care if it breaks the website or not. Please and thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Can you please share some code or possibly a sandbox link?

Answer (score 0):

is your content sized using px or some other similar unit. if so then change to % or something else or it else will have to scroll to show all the content and can't do that if overflow is hidden.